# OpenAPI support in react-admin?

Tags: swagger, openapi, react-admin

The [react-admin homepage](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/) prominently shows an OpenAPI (formerly Swagger) logo, but I can't find the relevant Data Provider in [the list](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html) or on GitHub. Is it best to use `ra-data-simple-rest` and extend it, or am I missing something and is there a ready-made adapter that parses an OpenAPI spec file?

Answer (score 2):

I was similarly confused and couldn't find any adapter or data provider for the same. Ended up writing my own data provider and figured out it was a breeze. The main point to note here is that it'll be different for every OpenAPI spec, based on the way the APIs are designed. Using the `swagger-client` makes it as simple as

```js
client.execute({
  method: 'get',
  parameters: { ...params },
  pathName: `/${resource}`,
})
```

for the `getList` method.

Answer (score 1):

As said by alanpoulain on [this github issue](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/4328#issuecomment-640077374), you can have a look at https://github.com/api-platform/admin.

> It's Hydra by default, but since it's based on https://github.com/api-platform/api-doc-parser, having an OpenAPI support should be doable.

Please let us know if you get it working !